# What is wrong with my datasource settings to get Spring Boot to connect to MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I followed the tutorial below to learn how to write Spring Boot app to access MySQL.

http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/10/27/using-mysql-in-spring-boot-via-spring-data-jpa-and-hibernate/

There is an error message with connection to the MySQL database. http://pastebin.com/ykYJacjZ

I believe something is wrong with the DataSource Settings. Below are my settings;

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3360/netgloo_blog
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = ''
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I am running a MySQL database using Xampp on port 3360. A database  'netgloo_blog' has been created. I have also created a table `users` with the fields `id`, `email`, `name`.

Comment: Please add the error to your post, don't let people follow links to get a complete picture of your problem..

Comment: @M. Deinum: Thanks and noted. I will usually do that but not in this case because the error message was too much to paste into the question.

Comment: password as `''` doesn't seem right, just use `spring.datasource.password=` if you don't have a password.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I put this as comment in the designated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried connecting to the MySQL server using the CLI?

```
mysql --host=localhost --port=3360 --user=root --password
```

I believe you either got the port wrong or the credentials. Default MySQL port is 3306, can it be a typo in the port-number you have specified?

Comment: Thanks. Correct answer! Careless of me. One more edit I need to make is `spring.datasource.password = ` for empty password.

Answer (score 2):

Not connecting to DB means there is failure with the DB connection. Either the credentials are not working or DB service is not reachable to your system. As your URL states that it is in your local system only. So, try connecting with the mysql CLI as already stated above by aksamit.

After providing the correct credentials even the below properties will work fine.

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3360/netgloo_blog
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password =
```

There is no need to specify the driverClassName util you want to use some non-generic driver class. Spring boot will select the driver based on the URL provided and the driver dependancy present in the pom.xml
Let us know if you still face issue while connecting to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to grant access to root from localhost.

If this persists I recommend you to create a new user into your sql and then try to enter with him.